# jQuery code working in FF, Chrome, not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a small snippet of code, this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#check").blur(function () {
                    var member = check.value;
                    $('#loading-image').show("fast");
                    $.getJSON('/Endpoint/MemberName/' + member, function (result) {
                        //  var data = JSON.parse(result);
                        var json = result;
                        if (json.result.length != 0) {
                            $("div#preload h2").html("Nombre: " + json.result[0].fullName);
                            jQuery('#services').show("fast");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("div#preload h2").html("No encontrado!");
                            jQuery('#services').hide("fast");
                        }
                        $('#loading-image').fadeOut("fast");

                    });
                });
            });
```

In Firefox and Chrome the snippet is working as intended, yet in IE browsers I get the following error:

SCRIPT5009: 'check' is undefined

Any idea on what could help me solve this issue?

EDIT: Added check textbox field:

```
            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Buscar numero de socio" id="check" name="check" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Añadir Cliente sin Cuenta
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: What versions of jQuery and IE?

Comment: Added the HTML for Check. It goes before the JS is declared. IE is IE11 and jQuery 2.2.0. As I said, works well with FF and Chrome.

Comment: Why aren't you using `this.value`? It's bad practice to try to treat element IDs as global variables even though browsers allow it, but that line is inside an event handler bound to the element in question, so `this.value` should work fine.

Comment: `$("div#preload h2")` would be better `$("#preload").find("h2")`

Comment: It is a given that a variable and element called `check` is a bit confusing since it is not a checkbox but a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var member = this.value;
var member = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Yeah it seems to be working, issue seems to be in var member = check.value;

Comment: you can get the check (html control) using *this* inside blur handler... var member = check.value;

Comment: oooh, I see where you are coming from. LEt me check

Comment: `$(this).is(":checked")` will always be false, because the element in question is `type="text"`.